# How can I see the referring domain of visitors who's source is a campaign?

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics, we have a campaign that is tracked as CPC, and has several possible sources. The campaign is tagged (using utm_campaign, utm_source and utm_medium) and tracking correctly, as are all the sources. One of the sources sends us traffic from several domains, but I see no way to separate out the domains in my reports.

So let's say the campaign is called "Stack Exchange" and the source could be 'Webmasters' or 'Web Applications'. If 'Webmasters' can send traffic from 'webmasters.stackexchange.com' or from 'www.stackexchange.com' - how can I see this info?

If I go to Traffic Sources > Sources > Campaigns and click the campaign and then the source in question, the only thing that shows up under the 'Source/Medium' column is the name of the source (like 'Webmasters'). It is not the same as going into Traffic Sources > Sources > Referrals, in this case the 'Source' column shows the domain, but campaign traffic is not included here.

It seems like if a referrer is tagged as being part of a campaign and has a source, the source in the tag overrides the referring domain. Is there a way to get the domain as well?

Comment: Have you looked at the Secondary Dimensions available for the report? There's a Placement URL dimension under Adwords, though it may require you to tag your URLs differently.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht Yea we dug around a lot in the secondary dimensions but no real luck there. I don't think we can make use of the placement URL because this isn't an adwords campaign. We keep coming back to the 'Source' option but that always just shows the name of the source instead of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
['utm_source', 'Web Masters '+document.domain]
```

By using the above in the GA code on the page in question, `utm_source` will be set to a Title (Web Masters) and also include the domain name of the server that returned the document(+document.domain). Thus a way of adding that info to `utm_source` and separating out the domains in the report.